# After moving code from body to a function, while loop won't execute

Tags: php, html

I have a working php script that utilizes this while loop successfully:

```
while ( $t_row = db_fetch_array( $t_result ) )
```

I am cleaning up my code and moved this to a function.  I can't get it to successfully iterate through the while loop:

```
function showProjects () {
    echo test1;
    while ( $t_row = db_fetch_array( $t_result ) )  {
        echo Test;
    }
    echo test2;
}
```

It will display test1 when called, but neither Test or test2 display.  Any advice?

Comment: post the error please

Comment: are `test1`, `Test` and `test2` supposed to be strings?

Comment: Yes, you should quote those 'strings'.

Comment: And echo $t_result inside the function to verify its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on strings...will apply in future

Answer (score 1):

If you had error reporting on you would see that `$t_result` is undefined. This is because it is in the global scope so the function does not have access to it. To solve this you need to pass it as a parameter to your function:

```
function showProjects ($t_result) {
    echo test1;
    while ( $t_row = db_fetch_array( $t_result ) )  {
        echo Test;
    }
    echo test2;
}

showProjects($t_result);
```